# RAM CARDS COMPATIBLITY, 2Rx8 and 1Rx8 RAM

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

**Specifications**

- Vaio SVE 11135CXW Laptop
- 750GB HARD DRIVE
- 4GB RAM Samsung 2GB 2Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-11-B2 DDR3 1600

I wish to upgrade to 8GB, I have found a similar Samsung card, Samsung 2GB 1Rx8 PC3-12800S-11-11-B2 DDR3 1600. The difference being that the existing card is 2Rx8 and new card is 1Rx8.

Are they compatible and if used together will they cause any instability or other problems?

I'm an engineer but with very little experience with computer building.

Comment: DDR3 is DDR3 provide the frequency and voltage is the same

Comment: So you want to add a 2GB DIMM for a total of 6GB? Should work fine, that laptop supports 8GB total maximum in 2 banks of 1 DIMM each. It will only operate in single channel mode, although I'm not sure if that chipset supports dual channel mode anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will work. Sony Vaio SVE11135CXW supports 2 x 4 GB Max DDR3 1333 MHz.

Refer this link
http://www.memorystock.com/memory/SonyVaioSVE11135CXW.html